# scheduling job after completion of previous job using rufus scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scheduled-tasks, rufus-scheduler, sidekiq

I have task_scheduler file as below,

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'rufus/scheduler'
      scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new


   scheduler.cron '0 20 * * *' do

     StartJOb1.perform_async
     Startjob2.perform_async
     Startjob3.perform_async
     Startjob4.perform_async
     Startjob5.perform_async

     end
```

I need to split these jobs and want to run Startjob4.perform_async
,     Startjob5.perform_async
after job1,job2 and job3 completes .the problem is I dont know how long it takes to complete these job.

I am using sidekiq for these background tasks

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with Cron, probably you should call next job from the current job.

And, you do not need sidekiq there, because of using cron.

Comment: Actually StartJOb1 is a class which performs some heavy function using sidekiq, I am just scheduling these workers using rufus scheduler.

Comment: @sumskyi u r answer is correct only u have to call each worker from each worker only after finishing the respective and there is no issue in calling worker from cron it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used sidekiq so not sure if this works.
You could try and use a semaphore or [Mutex](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Mutex.html) as it is called in rails. Something similar to this

```
mutex1, mutex2, mutex3 = new_mutexes_already_locked
StartJOb1.perform_async(mutex1) #-> unlocks mutex1 as soon as work is finished
Startjob2.perform_async(mutex2) #-> unlocks mutex2 as soon as work is finished
Startjob3.perform_async(mutex3) #-> unlocks mutex3 as soon as work is finished
Startjob4.perform_async(mutex1, mutex2, mutex3) #starts work if mutex1..3 unlocked
Startjob5.perform_async(mutex1, mutex2, mutex3) #dito
```

You could also start Job4+5 together with a single method and have this method wait to aquire a lock for mutex1..3

But i am not sure if this is a good fit for what you are doing and if it works with sidekiq as Mutex is actual for paralleling your own threads (thus it propably won't work over processes and i suppose sidekiq runs in it's own process?).

Alternative to a mutex you could write the state of the jobs into your database and poll from job 4 +5 to see when they have completed.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Sidekiq Superworker](https://github.com/socialpandas/sidekiq-superworker) for this, as it lets you define dependency graphs of workers. (As a disclaimer, I'm the gem's author.)